# MySQL count from one table while joining another

Tags: mysql

I don't know if it's just been a long day or what, but I cannot figure out the query that I need to run here.  We have two tables - One for leads generated and one for reports.  The leads table has basic lead info, along with the Source (Campaign) of the lead.  However, we need to know the number of leads that an ACCOUNT has received within a date range.  Here is the relevant table structure:

```
client_leads:
id
source
date

client_reports:
account
campaign
date
```

The 'source' column contains the same values as the 'campaign' column.  So, how would I achieve the following:

Say there are 10 leads in the leads table, each with the campaign that generated the lead.  There are 10 accounts in the reports table, each with hundreds of campaigns.  I need to list each account and how many leads it has in the leads table.

I just can't get the logic straight in my head.  I've tried everything that I can think of and it's just not working out for me.  If you need further explanation, let me know.  I'm trying to describe the problem to the best of my ability.

**Edit**:

```
CREATE TABLE `client_leads` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kw` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adgroup` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dayweek` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postal_code` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `preferred_phone` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alternate_phone` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `level_of_education` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `program_of_interest` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organic` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `site_id` (`site_id`),
  KEY `date_indeces` (`time`,`date`,`dayweek`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `site_id` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES `client_sites` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `client_reports` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `friendly_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sites_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adgroup` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `impressions` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clicks` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_cpc` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `avg_pos` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `stats` (`impressions`,`clicks`,`cost`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `campaign` (`campaign`),
  KEY `adgroup` (`adgroup`),
  KEY `keyword` (`keyword`),
  KEY `service` (`service`),
  KEY `sites_id` (`sites_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sites_id` FOREIGN KEY (`sites_id`) REFERENCES `client_sites` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=109167 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Edit Again:**
client_reports table data viewable at http://pastebin.com/T532W3Eq
client_leads table data viewable at http://pastebin.com/9cjWEvck

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT cr.account, cr.campaign, cr.date, COUNT(cl.id) AS number_of_leads
FROM client_reports cr
LEFT JOIN client_leads cl
ON cl.source = cr.campaign
GROUP BY cl.source
```

Comment: Same crazy results as I've been getting.  A ridiculously high number of leads, just like Chris' answer below.

Comment: can you export the data? I'll get my email address to you if you would like me to have a look...

Comment: Sorry - Had PC issues all weekend.  I can export a subset of the data if you want to have a look at it.  This is about to drive me insane because I know it's something small and simple.

Comment: @Kevin - if you contact me via twitter I'll send you my email.